# Running a Thread in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am making a simple button game with JavaFX and I need a thread to run so that I can check if an enemy or the player is alive or not. My problem is not starting and using the thread, but stopping it when the window is closed.

I made a sample class to demonstrate what I mean.

```
private Thread thread;
private boolean running;
private Stage window;

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    stopThread();
}

public synchronized void startThread() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Monitor");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stopThread() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    window = new Stage();
    window = stage;
    Pane layout = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

    window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        e.consume();
        close();
    });
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

public void close() {
    window.close();
    stopThread();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Things things = new Things();
    things.startThread();
    launch(args);
}
```

When I run it, "Hello" prints continuously, but when I try to close it, the thread keeps running and eclispe goes into debug mode saying:

`Thread [JavaFX Application Thread] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))
QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Supplier<T>) line: not available
GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(Window, long, int) line: not   available
WinWindow(Window).handleWindowEvent(long, int) line: not available
WinWindow(Window).notifyClose() line: not available
WinApplication._runLoop(Runnable) line: not available [native method]
WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Runnable) line: not available
2091156596.run() line: not available
Thread.run() line: not available`

I have looked around my code and cannot find anything that is null, though.

Comment: Are you exiting the application when you close the window, or are there other windows showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably hitting a livelock/deadlock situation.

In your run method, after the while loop terminates, you have your thread try to stop itself, and then attempt to wait for itself to die. That's a synchronized method, meaning only one thread can be running it at a time.

When you call it from your main method and try to stop the thread, it will try to join the thread and wait for it to die. Since this first call is already executing your `stopThread` method, when the while loop terminates in your run method, it will sit there and block, not causing the thread to die. Since the thread doesn't die, the first call to `stopThread` won't finish.

You could remove `stopThread` from your `run` method and it should behave better, though from what you posted here, it looks like a better design might be in order. I'd be curious if my suggestion works.

Upon further inspection, you also have a problem with static/non-static data within your threads.

I'm assuming your `Things` class implements `Runnable`, thus when you pass it to the `Thread` constructor and start it, it gets its *own copy* of the stack, and it's own local variables. When you call `stopThread` in your `close` method, you're not setting the proper `running` variable (it's not the one the thread running sees). If you make that field `static` and remove the `thread.join...` code, it behaves properly.

EDIT:
As a better design choice, it might be wiser to leverage the capability you get with Threads/Runnables and the way they are typically managed in an application (for more info, since you're using JFX, you should look at Services/Tasks)

Split up the thread implementation and the main class, and leverage the function of the thread itself to stop it.

Take this example, which is significantly cleaner, and works just as well:

```
public class Things implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running;  // this indicates it's running

    public Things() {
        running = true;  // thread is running when it's created (though not really until "run" is called)
    }

    // called from start()
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

    // call this method to stop the thread, from outside on the object reference
    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

In a separate Test/Application class, you can manipulate the `Things` reference to do what you want, without maintaining a reference to the actual thread.

```
public class Test extends Application {
    private Stage window;
    private static Things things;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window = new Stage();
        window = stage;
        Pane layout = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        window.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                close();
            }
        });
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }


    // on close
    public void close() {
        window.close();
        things.stop();  // stop the things object directly
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        things = new Things();  // create new runnable
        Thread t = new Thread(things,"Monitor"); // create thread
        t.start();  // start thread
        launch(args);  // launch app
    }
}
```

Comment: @James_D no worries, I was working on a suggested design when you posted, the more information the OP has, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Things` is the name of the class you showed, you're not stopping the correct thread.

When you call `launch(args)`, the FX Toolkit creates an instance of the application class (which I'm assuming is `Things`), creates a `Stage`, and passes the `Stage` to the application instance's `start(...)` method (executing that method on the FX Application Thread).

So you create one instance, and start the thread on that instance. Then the FX toolkit creates a second instance, and it's on that instance that you are trying to stop the thread. So you are stopping a different thread to the one you started.

The fix for this is to remove the lines

```
Things things = new Things();
things.startThread();
```

from your `main(...)` method, and just to add

```
this.startThread();
```

to the beginning of your `start(...)` method.

Additionally, as @RyanJ points out, you are deadlocking as you have one thread waiting on a second thread to complete, and both are trying to execute the same `synchronized` method. Also, you should declare `running` as `volatile`, since it is accessed from multiple threads:

```
private volatile boolean running ;
```

So this works:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Things extends Application implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private volatile boolean running;
    private Stage window;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//        stopThread();
        running = false ;
    }

    public synchronized void startThread() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Monitor");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stopThread() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        startThread();
        window = stage;
        Pane layout = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            close();
        });
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public void close() {
        window.close();
        stopThread();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

One last point: if this is the only window you have open, the JVM will exit when you close the window, as long as there are no *non-daemon* threads running. So you can just let the JVM kill your thread by making it a daemon thread. If this works for your real app, you could do any clean-up you needed by overriding the `stop` method:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Things extends Application implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private volatile boolean running;
    private Stage window;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//        stopThread();
        running = false ;
    }

    public synchronized void startThread() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Monitor");

        thread.setDaemon(true);

        thread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        startThread();
        window = stage;
        Pane layout = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```